# AngularJS : multiple resolves in ui.router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i'm trying achieve something like this :

```
 $stateProvider.state('app', {
        url: "/app",
        templateUrl: "assets/views/app.html",
        resolve: {
            authorize: ['authorization',
                function(authorization) {
                    return authorization.authorize();
                }
            ],
            loadSequence: loadSequence('chartjs', 'chart.js', 'chatCtrl')
        },
        abstract: true
```

resolving "authorize" then "LoadSequence" function, but the error i get is confusing  and i can't figure out how to do it properly :

> Error: ng:areq Bad Argument Argument 'fn' is not a function, got
>   Object

Best regards.

Comment: Did you fix it? Were you able to inject authorize in the controller? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to wrap the second item in `resolve` in a function like you did the first one:

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    templateUrl: "assets/views/app.html",
    resolve: {
        authorize: ['authorization',
            function(authorization) {
                return authorization.authorize();
            }
        ],
        loadSequence: function(){
            return loadSequence('chartjs', 'chart.js', 'chatCtrl');
        }
    },
    abstract: true
```

Also, if `loadSequence` does not return a promise, it needs to.